# Dropping the columns that contain NaN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this one

```
             A    M    DM   BYN    Z
2015-01-02   3.   7.  NaN    2.    8.
2015-01-03   1.  NaN   2.    8.    3.
...
2016-06-14   3.   1.   7.   NaN    2.
2016-06-15   1.  NaN   2.    8.    3.
```

My actual DataFrame contains more than 500 columns and more than a year of history.

I would like:

1. to drop the columns where the last row contains a NaN
2. or alternatively, to drop the columns where there is at least a NaN in the last 5 rows

I am able to identify the columns that contain NaN:

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=0)
```

But I am not able to drop the columns in the above mentioned cases.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas has a method just for this [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
In [21]: df.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
Out[21]:
              A    Z
2015-01-02  3.0  8.0
2015-01-03  1.0  3.0
2016-06-14  3.0  2.0
2016-06-15  1.0  3.0
```

---

You can use ~ (not) [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
In [11]: df.loc[:, ~df.isnull().any()]
Out[11]:
              A    Z
2015-01-02  3.0  8.0
2015-01-03  1.0  3.0
2016-06-14  3.0  2.0
2016-06-15  1.0  3.0
```

Though perhaps this is better written as all notnull:

```
In [12]: df.loc[:, df.notnull().all()]
Out[12]:
              A    Z
2015-01-02  3.0  8.0
2015-01-03  1.0  3.0
2016-06-14  3.0  2.0
2016-06-15  1.0  3.0
```

> drop the columns where there is at least a NaN in the last 5 rows

You can use this on the last rows ([`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)) of the DataFrame:

```
df.loc[:, df.tail(5).notnull().all()]
```

Comment: same method also has `thresh` argument where you can specify how many `NA`'s necessitate a drop.

Comment: and `subset` which is really useful too http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: what about checking only the last row or the last 5 rows, as stated in the question?

Comment: @vsoler use `df.loc[:, df.tail(5).notnull().all()]`

Answer (score 2):

To only keep columns where the last row has no missing values, ie dropping those that do, you can create a [`boolean index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on the columns using a negated `.isnull()` (or `.notnull()`):

```
df.loc[:, ~df.iloc[-1].isnull()]
df.loc[:, df.iloc[-1].notnull()]
```

Using just the first two rows of your sample data:

```
              A   DM  BYN    Z
2015-01-02  3.0  NaN  2.0  8.0
2015-01-03  1.0  2.0  8.0  3.0
```

For the last five rows, keeping only the columns where there is not at least one `nan` value, you would be adding `.any()` or `.all()` depending on whether you go with `.isnull()` or `.notnull()`:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.iloc[-5:].isnull().any()]
df.loc[:, df.iloc[-5:].notnull().all()]
```